# how rename a folder inside project template to project's name? (visual studio template customization)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, templates, customization

I created a project template in Visual Studio 2010. When I click on `Project` -> `File` -> `Export Template`, I get a zip file in the Visual Studio template folder. In the solution, I have a folder named `Test`.

When I create a solution from that template *(from `add` -> `new project dialog`)*, I want to rename the `Test` folder's name to the solution's name automatically.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

1. Get the files out of the zip file
2. In "MyTemplate.vstemplate", change `TargetFolderName="Test"` to `TargetFolderName="$projectname$"`
3. In the .csproj file, change everything that refers to folder "Test" to "$projectname$" (including paths, etc.)

This should work.

Additional info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahkztdcb.aspx (Visual Studio project template info)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx (Visual Studio template macros reference)

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: Updated the links (maybe). Quit slaying your kin plz.