# Add postfix to .NET project template autogenerated solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, templates

I have a .NET project template using the dotnet new template engine, with a template.json.

The naming of the project is working just fine. I'm using a sourcename, and the csproj file is called SourceName-postfix.csproj. That ends up being renamed just fine, using the ProjectName specified in VS on project creation.

However I cannot figure out how to force the solution file to have the same postfix.
The project template includes a solution file, which is correctly being renamed, but VS keeps adding a second solution file which is only called ProjectName.sln. I don't need that one. I want the one that is part of the template.

If I turn the template into a solution template instead of a project template, then it doesn't add a 2nd solution file, but instead renames the original one, removing the postfix.

The sources { "rename" } feature doesn't seem to work on this.

This section in template.json is ineffective

```
  "sources": [
    {
      "rename": {
        "SourceName.sln": "SourceName-blend.sln"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Please refer to these links. http://json.schemastore.org/template  and  https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Testing-your-templates.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I need a bit more help than RTFM. I did read those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how rename a folder inside project template to project's name? (visual studio template customization)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190741/how-rename-a-folder-inside-project-template-to-projects-name-visual-studio-te)

Comment: Not really no. I never figured it out.  
@DannyThunder